# Homeomorphism of a Torus

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, open-map

I need to show that the function:

$f(u,v)=((r \cos(u)+a)\cos(v), (r\cos(u)+a)\sin(v), r\sin(u))$, $f:U\to\mathbb{R^3}$, when $U=(0,2\pi)\times (0,2\pi)$ is an homeomorphism to the torus.

I show that $f$ is differentiable and then $f$ is continous, also I show that $f$ is injetive.
I tried to calculate the inverse function...but I'm stucked.

Also...I tried to show that $f$ is an open function...but I don't know how I can start the proof.

Answer (score 2):

Well, they're not homeomorphic, as $(0, 2\pi) \times (0, 2\pi)$ has a trivial fundamental group, while $S^1 \times S^1$ does not.

Comment: An easier topological invariant: $(0, 2\pi) \times (0, 2\pi)$ is not compact, but $S^1 \times S^1$ is compact.

Comment: Isn’t f(u,v) the formula of a torus  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus. Try the Inverse Function Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

Comment: The inverse function theorem only guarantees that the function will be a *local* homeomorphism.

Comment: Ouch, now i to redo proof